# TypeScript set different baseUrl in different project subfolders

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tsconfig

I'm currently in the need to migrate a create-react-app to NextJS 13 framework.
My idea is:

- start a mew NextJS 13 project from scratch (so with the App router pattern)
- move all my cra files into a src subdirectoy of my Next project
- import the App 'cra' component in the main next page with the 'use client' directive.

Ideally, this process would let me be able to gradually migrate the application to the new framework having a working starting point.

In the cra src directory my imports are absolute because the tsconfig.json file of the create-react-app had the baseUrl options set to "src":

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "baseUrl": "src"
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

in the App component:

```
./
 |--....
 |--public/
 |--src/
     |--App/
         |--App.component.tsx
     |--routes/
          |...
```

an import looks like this:

```
import BuildRoutes from 'routes/BuildRoutes';
```

Now, this very same App component in the Next Project would sit in a src subFolder at the same level of his original parent:

```
./
 |--.next/
 |--app/
 |--...
 |--src/
     |--App/
         |--App.component.tsx
     |--routes/
          |...
```

but the tsconfig.json looks different:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Now, obviously, all the absolute imports in the src subdirectory are broken.
Any idea on how to fix this, a part of going through each and every file and manually fix them?
Is it possible to set different baseUrl in different directories of the project, so that I can set in src directory a different base url from the rest of the project and avoid modifying all the import statements?